# AngularJS and BrightCove Media API

Tags: angularjs, brightcove

I am working on integrating BrightCove into an Ionic App (allows HTML and JS/Angular to run as a native app on mobile devices).

The app will play videos and allow user's to download the video to save the user's device, I can get the app to play the video but am having issues getting the 
Media API to run the '*find_video_by_id*' call.

So I have a download button which triggers the following function

```
_this.downloadBrightcoveVideo = () => {
    let searchParams = {}

    BCMAPI.token = 'xxxx..'
    BCMAPI.callback = 'useDownloadLink'
    BCMAPI.command = 'find_video_by_id'
    searchParams.video_id = 1234567890
    searchParams.media_delivery = 'HTTP'
    searchParams.video_fields = 'FLVURL'

    BCMAPI.find (BCMAPI.command, searchParams)
}
```

where *token* and *video_id* are set to my video and URL Access token.

I have tried setting the useDownloadLink function as below

```
let useDownloadLink = function () { console.log ("I'm Alive") }
```

or

```
function useDownloadLink () { console.log ("I'm Alive") }
```

or

```
_this. useDownloadLink = () => { console.log ("I'm Alive") }
```

Every time I run the code I get the error below, even though I have useDownloadLink above the download function

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: useDownloadLink is not defined
```

I have tried several variations now and nothing is working, any solution would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance,
Áine

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of Google-ing came to the conclusion it was better to use BrightCove's CMS Api to achieve the results I wanted, once going through the api it was actually pretty simple..

Hope that helps someone else :D

Happy Coding!